# Variable scope in XSLT

Tags: xslt, variables, scope

I am having an issue trying to figure out var scoping on xslt. What I actually want to do it to ignore 'trip' tags that have a repeated 'tourcode'.

**Sample XML:**

```
<trip>
 <tourcode>X1</tourcode>
 <result>Budapest</result>
</trip>
<trip>
 <tourcode>X1</tourcode>
 <result>Budapest</result>
</trip>
<trip>
 <tourcode>X1</tourcode>
 <result>Budapest</result>
</trip>
<trip>
 <tourcode>Y1</tourcode>
 <result>london</result>
</trip>
<trip>
 <tourcode>Y1</tourcode>
 <result>london</result>
</trip>
<trip>
 <tourcode>Z1</tourcode>
 <result>Rome</result>
</trip>
```

**XSLT Processor:**

```
<xsl:for-each select="trip">    
    <xsl:if test="not(tourcode = $temp)">
      <xsl:variable name="temp" select="tour"/>
      // Do Something (Print result!)
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**Desired Output:**
Budapest london Rome

Comment: Title of the question would have been .. something like,

"Removing duplicate nodes from xml using XSLT"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Desired Output**: Budapest london Rome

What you are after is *grouping* output by city name. There are two common ways to do this in XSLT.

One of them is this:

```
<xsl:template match="/allTrips">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="trip" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="trip">
  <!-- test if there is any preceding <trip> with the same <result> -->
  <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::trip[result = current()/result])">
    <!-- if there is not, output the current <result> -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="result" />
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

And the other one is called Muenchian grouping and @Rubens Farias just posted an answer that shows how to do it.

Comment: Thanks mate, even though out of 4 duplicates it still shows 2 but it is getting me closer to what I had in mind.

Comment: @Mazzi: It does? It did not when I tested it with your sample. If you post the actual XML and XSL you work with I am sure I can point out what's wrong.

Comment: @Tomalak: The xsl and xml are bit bulky, I tried to simplify them as much as possible. I don't know if stackoverflow has a send message functionality?! So I can send it to you directly.

Comment: I don't believe that your output is still having duplicates, If you say it is repeating then use this condition <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::trip[result = current()/result or tourcode = current()/tourcode]) .. I guess this should work ..

Comment: @Mazzi: No, there is no messaging functionality. Either you put it into your question, or you upload it to one of those pastebin websites and post a link.

Comment: @infant programmer: Better not guess, it's not worth it when looking at the real code is possible. ;)

Comment: @Tomalak, I know my suggestion isn't worth on condition we expect .. when Mazzi said it doesn't work (with his HUGE XML) .. I assumed his XML might have some kind of the MIXED TAGS (tourcode isn't mapping to result as he has mentioned in exmple) .. what sin in trying .. ;-)

Comment: lol, I have paste the xsl and its here: http://tinypaste.com/3941f (I have added some comment on the top) and the xml is located here: http://www.intrepidtravel.com/xml/latestock
Cheers,

Comment: @Mazzi: I've uploaded an all-new version of your XSLT to http://tinypaste.com/f3a23. Feel free to ask followup questions and have fun figuring it out. :-)

Comment: Umm I don't know how to say it, but it is not in price order?! lol Is it left for me to figure out?

Comment: @Mazzi: No, it was meant to be in the right order. ;) It was when I tested it, but maybe I made some kind of mistake. I will check again tomorrow.

Comment: @Mazzi: Oh damn. I've made one small mistake in the `<xsl:sort>`. The sort expression is incorrect, but only by a tiny bit. It's rather obvious, I trust you find it very quickly. :)

Comment: @Tomalak: Only if I pick you as the best answer lol. Worked like a charm.. ThanQ

Comment: @Mazzi: Yeah, that's the deal. ;) For the record: The correct version is at http://tinypaste.com/d1dc9f

Answer (score 24):

You **can't** change variables in XSLT.

You need to think about it more as [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) instead of procedural, because XSLT is a functional language. Think about the variable scoping in something like this pseudocode:

```
variable temp = 5
call function other()
print temp

define function other()
  variable temp = 10
  print temp
```

What do you expect the output to be? It should be `10 5`, not `10 10`, because the `temp` inside the function `other` isn't the same variable as the `temp` outside that function.

It's the same in XSLT. Variables, once created, cannot be redefined because they are write-once, read-many variables by design.

If you want to make a variable's value defined conditionally, you'll need to define the variable conditionally, like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="temp">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(tourcode = 'a')">
      <xsl:text>b</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:text>a</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:if test="$temp = 'b'">
  <!-- Do something -->
</xsl:if>
```

The variable is only defined in one place, but its value is conditional. Now that `temp`'s value is set, it cannot be redefined later. In functional programming, variables are more like read-only parameters in that they can be set but can't be changed later. You must understand this properly in order to use variables in any functional programming language.

Comment: Sorry mate, you answer was great, however I have change the question a bit to get it closer to what I am after. Thanks

Comment: @Mazzi: Always write question towards what you want to do (input->desired output), never just towards *how* you think you can do it. In this case: You do not want to change variable values, you want to produce a list of unique values from the input.

Comment: Someone should change the question, so this answer fits again. It's much better than the question. Questions are overrated anyway...

Comment: Sorry guys for changing the question. Now I got my answer what do you want me to change the question to?

Comment: [I have a larger number of variables and they all depend on the same two tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30122497/xslt-keep-multiple-variables-in-scope-depending-on-a-single-test) - is there a way to test only twice but keep the variables in scope?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:key name="trip" match="trip" use="result" />

  <xsl:template match="/trips">

    <xsl:for-each select="trip[count(. | key('trip', result)[1]) = 1]">
      <xsl:if test="position() != 1">, </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="result"/>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```